# How to get data from additional table in many to many relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a many to many relationship between tables 'products' and 'recipes'. I created table product_recipe to handle this and my table looks like:

id | recipe_id | product_id | amount

In my blade file I use

```
@foreach($recipe->product as $row)
        <p>{{ $row->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

to get a name of used products in recipe. How I can get an amount of product which is stored in product_recipe table? Do I have to create a model for product_recipe table and get it from model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to declare the relationship wants to include the extra pivot information so that the pivot object that is attached to the records will have more than just the 'id's:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('amount');
}
```

Now the `pivot` object will include the field `amount`:

```
foreach ($recipe->products as $product) {
    echo $product->pivot->amount;
}
```

> "By default, only the model keys will be present on the `pivot` object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship"

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Many To Many - Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) `withPivot`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `pivot` attribute.

```
  @foreach($recipe->product as $row)
    <p>{{ $row->pivot->field_name}}</p>
  @endforeach
```

No need to create Model for `product_recipe`. Just specify table name in relation of two Models.

Like `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_recipe')->withPivot('amount');` and similar for other model.

Comment: I used pivot like you said but thats returns nothing. I declared table name in models but thats not working anyway :(  Foreach return $row->name but $row->pivot->amount is one line lower and there is nothing :/

Comment: @JaroslawNowak because you have to declare on the relationship that you want the extra pivot information, added an answer that specifies that

Comment: @JaroslawNowak as  suggested I have updated answer.

Comment: @lagbox  Your answer is correct. Thank you so much.